# terminals and C

Tags: c

I am reading a book called "beginning linux programming". I would like to ask about this line of code (from page 204):

```
if (output_stream) putc(char_to_write, output_stream);
```

I can't understand this line.
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/putc. Read that. If you still don't understand please describe specifically what you don't understand.

Comment: is (output_stream) is a type cast of the return value of putc? and if that is true, why it is cast to pointer of FILE (page 203)?

Comment: No it's not. There's an `if` in front of that. So `(output_stream)` is the conditional for the `if`. That is, `putc` will only get called if `output_stream` is not NULL.

Comment: @MohammedAshour: `if (condition) statement;` is an if-statement, not a cast.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you very much Alan, thank you very much Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
if (output_stream) putc(char_to_write, output_stream);
```

`if(output_stream)` is a condition. If `output_stream` is not `NULL`, then the `putc` will execute.

The function `putc` with declaration `int putc (int char, FILE *stream)` writes a character (an `unsigned char`) specified by the argument `char` to the specified `stream` and advances the position indicator for the stream.
In short, it writes a character(first argument) to its second argument.